# How to make a URL Shortener work without reloading a page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, single-page-application, url-shortener

I'm running php URL Shortener on my website. I have the following code on my index.php file.

```
<form action="create.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="longurl" placeholder="long url"><br/>
<input type="text" name="shortword" placeholder="short name"><br/>
<img src="captcha.php"><input type="text" name="captcha"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Create Short URL"></form>
```

and i have the following code on create.php file

```
<?php
if($error == '0')
{
echo 'Success!. '.$longurl.' has shortened to mysite.com/'.$shortword.'';
}
else
{
echo 'Error Occured';
}
?>
```

I want to make this form submitted without loading the page using AJAX or something like that. However i never tried something like AJAX or JQUERY before. It will greatly help me if someone give me a step by step instruction on making this website as a single page application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think something universal should looks like that:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var query = '';
    $(this).find("input").each(function(){
       var name = $(this).prop("name");
       var value = $(this).val();
       query = query + '&' + name + '=' + value;
    });
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "myformhandler.php",
        data: query,
         success: function(msg)
          {
             alert ("wow i just submited my form!")
           }
     })
})
```